# JavaScript : How to calculate days count from two dates based on month

Tags: javascript, date, date-range

For example,

```
var from_date = new Date('2014-8-28');
var to_date = new Date('2014-9-3');
```

From these two date range, i need to calculate no. of days based on month.

How can I get this?

My expected result is,

```
[
  {
    "month" : 8,
    "days"  : 4  // In month of August 28, 29, 30 & 31 has totally 4 days
  },
  {
    "month" : 9,
    "days"  : 3  // In month of September 1, 2 & 3 has totally 3 days
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those look like invalid dates to me ?

Comment: Use js String.split('-') function for get the day and month but where here to help when you try something and get stuck not to do all of your work when you didn't pass at least a second on your problem

Comment: suggest doing this at server side where you have easy API to achieve this..For java its Calendar API

Comment: So where are you stuck? SO is for *specific* questions with specific answers. This reads a bit like "please code this for me". The simplest way to do what you're asking is a straightforward loop: Start with 2014-08-28 and continue through 2014-09-03, moving forward a day at a time, counting the number of days you see in each month.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I don't know where I could start this. I'm new to JS.

Comment: @adeneo : Sorry I updated my question.

Comment: You have JavaScript questions dating back to March 2013. How can you still be new? You've still not described where you're stuck. What's the first thing you need to do that you don't know how to do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Nah, I'm just cranky. It's 3:40 AM here and I've been banging my head against Closure Compiler all day/night. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of teaching, see comments:

```
var stopDate = new Date("2014-09-04");  // One day AFTER the last date we care
                                        // about
var results = [];                       // An array for our results, initially
                                        // empty
var date = new Date("2014-08-28");      // Our starting date
var entry;                              // The "current" month's entry in the loop
while (date < stopDate) {

    // Create a new entry if necessary.
    // The `!entry` bit uses the fact that variables start out with the value
    // `undefined`, and `undefined` is "falsey", so `!entry` will be true if
    // we haven't put anything in `entry` yet. If we have, it's an object
    // reference, and object references are "truthy", so `!entry` will be
    // false. The second check is to see whether we've moved to a new month.
    if (!entry || entry.month !== date.getMonth() + 1) {

        // Create a new entry. This creates an object using an object initialiser
        // (sometimes called an object "literal")
        entry = {
            month: date.getMonth() + 1, // +1 because `getMonth` uses 0 = January
            days:  0                    // Haven't counted any days yet
        };

        // Add it to the array
        results.push(entry);
    }

    // Count this day
    ++entry.days;

    // Move to next day
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);   // JavaScript's `Date` object handles
                                        // moving to the next month for you
}
```

About "falsey" and "truthy": In most languages, you can only use booleans (true or false) for branching, but JavaScript allows coercing values to booleans. "Falsey" values are values that coerce to false. They are: `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""`, and of course `false`. "Truthy" values are everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working flawlessly. But it returns `2` no. of days in the month `September` . It should be `3`

Comment: @Ranjith: No worries. It returns 3 if you use it correctly, see the comment on the first line.

Comment: Yeah... :). Either ways, I just change `less than or equal to(<=) ` in `while` loop condition. It returns perfectly. Thanks..

Comment: @Ranjith: I wouldn't do that. I'd add one to the final date. I can't say why exactly, it shouldn't matter, but that's what I'd do. :-)